# What is this port, 15x4, missing (13,4), possibly video

Tags: video, port, dvi

I am trying to connect to an old (circa 2007) Linux box that I use for image processing. I've never had to connect to the box physically, I always did everything over telnet. But now I want to access it directly.

I tried to hook up a monitor but it doesn't have vga or dvi. All it has is this weird port that I cannot identify.

It's not dvi (that would require a bar pin and 3 vertical pins).

This has 15 horizontal, 4 vertical, and missing pin 13, 4 (top left is 1,1).

I can't post images right now due to low  rep. I'll upload images when I can. It's white, boxy, dvi-looking. This is it:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GS1icd2d6vaEQMPMf89y4v6JnB_oMkov

Pins:

```
............... 
............... 
............... 
............ ..
```

Shape:

```
________
\______/
```

Color: white

Attached via pci card, not mobo.

What is this port? If it is video, what are the specs/outputs or converter to get it into something useful?

Comment: Does it look like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCART

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GS1icd2d6vaEQMPMf89y4v6JnB_oMkov

Good idea with the link! This is my pic.

Comment: Reminds me of the proprietary connectors used as break out for little connector hubs.

Comment: Your picture is pretty blury, but it looks like the female [DVI connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface).

Comment: I thought that at first but it's missing a row of pins. And there isn't a vertical or horizontal bar.

Comment: @Tallima, yeah, and now that I look at it more closely its also missing the analog signal pins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a single-port dual-monitor vga/dvi connector called a DMS-59 (Dual Monitor Solution-59 pin). You need a "Y" adapter to split out to VGA or DVI

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59

Comment: I would check the card specs to see if it supports/prefers dvi over vga etc. before choosing an adapter